# When is it necessary to use StandardScaler/MinMaxScaler on y_train and y_test?

Tags: data, data-cleaning, preprocessing, feature-scaling

I have been through various kernels where scaling is done on y_train and y_test and many where there isn't. Is there any specific rule which should be followed when to or when not to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, scaling target values is not the common practice, though I do not expect it to change results much. Here is a more detailed discussion of this issue:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re